# Processing cycle for

Tags: processing

I need of draw these two line with cycle for of processing 
and I do not know how to do!
[image]

Comment: Tag the language name that you're using! And also mention what you've tried till now and what problems  you face!

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a programming question? This site is for questions. Not a place to dump your todo/requirements list and apparently expect others to do your job for you.

Comment: First, play with a [for loop to draw lines](https://processing.org/reference/for.html), then either use [modulo(%)](https://processing.org/reference/modulo.html) or a combination of [boolean](https://processing.org/reference/boolean.html) and [! (logical NOT)](https://processing.org/reference/logicalNOT.html) to alternate how you draw a line at each iteration of the for loop. Once you draw this once, it should be easy to call the same **function**ality again to draw a second zig-zag. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

```
int point1 = 50;
```

This is the starting point part of the diagonal squiggle.

```
int point2 = 100;
```

This is the next point to plot, can also be interpreted as the width.

```
 int s = 20;
```

This is the height of each diagonal squiggle.

```
void draw(){
   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i+=20){
       line(point1, i, point2, s);
       int temp = point1;
       point1 = point2;
       point2 = temp;
       s += 20;
}
```